# Take a set $D$, under what condition does there exists $\epsilon$ such that $x + \epsilon y \in D$.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, for each $x \in \mathbb{D}, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, under what condition does there exists
>    $\epsilon > 0$ $x + \epsilon y \in D$?

Is such $\epsilon$ always possible?

Clearly not, if $D$ is closed and we pick a point on the boundary.

My hunch is that $\epsilon > 0$ exists if $D$ is open.

Comment: You said "Under what condition does there exists
 $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x + \epsilon y \in D$, $\forall x \in D,
 \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$?". Did you instead mean "Under what condition does, $\forall x \in D $ and $
 \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  there exist
 $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x + \epsilon y \in D$?"

Comment: So is it one $\epsilon$ that works for all $x,y$.  Or for each $x,y$, you can find an $\epsilon$

Comment: @NazimJ It should be for each

Comment: I'd say if and only if $D=\Bbb R^n\lor D=\emptyset$ by evaluating the defining property in $y=\frac{z-x}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @ShamisenExpert If it should be "for each", then please correct the question such that the answer of NazimJ becomes correct. Otherwise I have to agree with Gae. S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely $D$ being open works:

If $||y||_2 = 0$, then the statement is trivially fulfilled.

Assume $||y||_2 \neq 0$.  Given any $x\in D$ and $B_\delta (x) \subseteq D$, then for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we can choose 
$$ \epsilon = \frac{\delta}{||y||_2} > 0 $$
Then we have that
$$ ||x - (x + \epsilon y ) ||_2 = || \epsilon y  ||_2 = \delta \leq \delta $$
Namely, $(x + \epsilon y) \in B_\delta (x) \subseteq D$

Comment: Great, exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Your $\epsilon$ changes depending on $x$ and $y$, whereas the problem right now reads $$(\exists \epsilon >0)(\forall x\in D)(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n)\ x+\epsilon y\in D$$

Comment: A minor correction in the proof: It should say "for any $y\in\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$, since you devide by $\|y\|$. For $y=0$ the statement it trivially fulfilled.

Comment: @Gae.S. in the comments OP confirms that for each $x,y$ we can find an $\epsilon$.  If not then my answer is totally not correct